# Programatically painting pixels on the screen at the max (or next to) refresh rate (eg 60 hz) on linux?

Tags: linux, graphics

I'm looking into rendering frames at a high rate (ideally next to the max monitor rate) and I was wondering if anyone had any idea at what level I should start looking into: kernel/driver level (OS space) ? X11 level ? svgalib (userspace) ?

Comment: Did you try using some existing graphical toolkit (like Gtk or Qt)?

Answer (score 1):

On a modern computer, you can do it using the ordinary tools and APIs for graphics.  If you have full frames full of random pixels, a simple [bit blit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) from an in-memory buffer will perform more than adequately.  Without any optimization work, I found that I could generate more than 500 frames per second on Windows XP using 2008 PCs.